# split large CSV on the column value (order date) into small CSV and add double quotes to Order Comments Column through R

Tags: r, csv

I have csv file like this

```
customerid orderid paymentamount   orderdate         ordernotes
1213        1233     16.99        01/01/2017 0:05     abcd acd cbvfd
1222        2343     44.99        01/01/2017 1:05     xyzzz
1234        4565     20.99        01/01/2017 2:05   
1267        6754     11.99        01/02/2017 0:05     abcdabv
1785        8975     12.99        01/02/2017 1:05     xsdsgff
7654        7657     13.99        01/03/2017 2:00 
6545        7867     10.99        01/03/2017 4:00     1/7 xyzzz
                                                      2/8 abcd
```

I have many rows of data and want to split this large CSV on the basis of orderdate into seprate CSV on the basis of each day. I tried this but not getting any results.I also want to add double quotes to order notes column.

```
x1 <- read.csv("xyz.csv", header=T, sep=",")
for (date in levels(x1$orderdate)){
  tmp=subset(x1,orderdate== date)
  fn=paste('x1/',gsub(' ','',date),sep='')
  write.csv(tmp,fn,row.names=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: have a look at read.csv. there might already be some splitting options. look here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/efficiency-of-importing-large-csv-files-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the `orderdate`column to class date, extract unique dates and go on splitting:

```
library(lubridate)

x$orderdate <- strptime(x$orderdate, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
for (d in date(x$orderdate)){
  tmp <- subset(x, date(orderdate) == d)
  # do stuff...
}
```

Comment: It gives me + in the end when i run the code and nothing shows up

Comment: Missing parentheses somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like:

```
x1 <- read.csv("xyz.csv", sep=",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
lapply(unique(as.Date(x1$orderdate, "%d/%m/%Y")), function(d) {
  df <- x1[as.Date(x1$orderdate, "%d/%m/%Y")==d,]
  invisible(write.csv(df, sprintf("%s.csv", as.character(d))))
})
```

Comment: ..It is giving me + at the end when i run the code..and nothing shows up

Comment: @jsingh apologies, errors corrected and tested with your data.

Comment: @anthonyserious..How i can write these into separate CSV?

Comment: @jsingh the code already does that for you - for each date, it creates a CSV named `YYYY-MM-DD.csv` for each unique date in `x1$orderdate`.  See the `write.csv` part on line 4.